# eclipse wont build because of desktop.ini

Tags: android, eclipse

Just updated SDK and ADT, and running a test project here now, I can't get it to build.

Android AAPT problem "invalid resource directory name", and the problem is desktop.ini which is placed in all of the res folders. It just gets put back if I delete it. The desktop.ini's also prevent r.java from being built as it depends on a clean res folder.

My workspace is on a Google Drive directory if that matters. Thanks!

Comment: Came here because I experienced that too today. Google Drive clutters all directories with desktop.ini files and Eclipse has a problem with that. It's not the first time that Eclipse shows problems with Cloud systems.

Comment: Try this out. It has a solution to disable this Windows behavior. Only applicable if you don't need this Windows feature. [Solution to supress re-generating desktop.ini](http://jamesisin.com/a_high-tech_blech/index.php/2010/09/nevermore-be-bothered-by-desktop-ini/)

Answer (score 0):

I use google drive and I come across the same problem, please use windows folder browser search to search desktop.ini in the whole project folder, so that you can select all and delete them all at once. Don' t try to delete one by one in the folder. (I have 1000+ desktop.ini in the whole project)